# Product of $\mathbb{R}_{disc}$ metrizable

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Show that $X=\prod\limits_{n=1}^\infty\mathbb{R}_{disc}$ is metrizable.

I know that there are 2 different directions I could take:

1. Show that $X$ is regular and has a countably locally finite basis
2. Define an embedding $j:X\rightarrow Y$ onto a metrizable space $Y$

I'm not sure which is easier/more appropriate. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Is that the discrete topology?

Answer (score 0):

I would choose a third direction by defining a metric on $X$ similar to that of [Baire space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_space_(set_theory)) as follows. For any points $x=(x_n)$ and $y=(y_n)$ of $X$ put $N(x,y)=\min\{n:x_n\ne y_n\}$ and 
$d((x_n),(y_n))=2^{-N(x,y)}$.